# Why are Google Maps 'GroundOverlay's rendered differently than 'Rectangle's when their bounding boxes cross the 180th meridian?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having an issue with a JS Google Map, with a ground overlay with bounds that cross the 180th meridian (when the Longitude changes from 180 to -180). It is rendered incorrectly, with it being stretched between the bounds the wrong way around.
Are there any work-arounds to this issue, assuming it is a bug in Google Maps?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.64, 172.44)
  });

  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-43.64, 172.44),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-16.689999999999998, -179.87)
    );

    var overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds);
  overlay.setMap(map);

  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: imageBounds
  });
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/peteroomen/m2e4d57x/15/

Comment: Found [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112755552). It's still unassigned and in a `new` status. You can star the issue and link to this question in a comment, as there was no example provided. And hope they have a look.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next API release as per the issue tracker (link in the above comment).